# Checking if all entries in a list are in a string

Tags: python, string, list, iterator

I have the following code:

```
sent = 'My name is Karen and I drive a black car.'
l = ['Karen', 'black']
print all(words in l for words in sent)
```

This snippet of code is returning False, when I thought it would return true. I am confused why. Could someone explain to me what is going on? Thank you!

Comment: Just because you use the name `words` in `for words in sent` doesn't mean that Python knows you need to split on word-boundaries then iterate over those individual words... *you need to implement that*. Of course, as others have pointed out, the logic of what you are trying to do here anyway is not exactly correct either.

Comment: `{'Karen', 'black'}.issubset('My name is Karen and I drive a black car.'.split())`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're iterating through the wrong list and checking against the wrong item

```
all(word in sent for word in l)
```

Comment: This is not necessarily correct. This test if any strings in `l` are _sub-strings_ of `sent`, rather than a word in `sent`. For example, your solution would incorrectly return `True` for `sent == 'My name is Karen and I drive a RblackR car.'`.

Comment: @ChristianDean Depends on how strict the OP is being.  Question just wanted to know if the entries in a list existed in a string, it didn't specify that they wanted them to exist *exactly* as that word.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here:

1. When you iterate over a string, you iterate over each *character*. You need to iterate over each word. In your case, you can use `str.split`
2. You need to test if all the words in `l` are in the list of words in `sent`. Not visa versa.

With the above changes, your code would be:

```
>>> sent = 'My name is Karen and I drive a black car.'
>>> words = sent.split()
>>> l = ['Karen', 'black']
>>> 
>>> all(word in words for word in l)
True
```

Comment: @vaultah Fixed. Sorry about that. I was preoccupied with something else and thought I'd post an answer. Guess I need to pay more attention.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the string `sent`, which is taking each character from that string. You have to iterate over the words in `l`:

```
all(i in sent for i in l)
```

Comment: This is not necessarily correct. This test if any strings in l are sub-strings of sent, rather than a word in sent. For example, your solution would incorrectly return True for: sent = 'My name is Karen and I drive a RblackR car.'.

Comment: @ChristianDean that is going beyond the scope of the OP's question. The OP is merely asking if a word itself exists in `sent`, rather than existing as a substring of an element of `sent`.